# MySQL - Creating records in table 2 on creation in table 1

Tags: mysql, insert

Say I have 2 tables, **ballplayers** and **stats** in my Database.

when I add a **ballplayers** record (add someone new to the team) is there a way to create a new entry for that player in the **stats** table as well?

```
    ballplayers                           stats
 id, playername, number          id, totalpts, totalrebounds
```

(they are referenced using the id column in each table.)

So like this... Say I add to **ballplayers**

```
    ballplayers
 id, playername, number
  1    Nick        22
```

How can MySQL create a new entry in **stats** which is triggered on that entry creation in **ballplayers** with the given **id** and having defaults of totalpts and totalrebounds set to 0?

```
    stats
 id, totalpts, totalrebounds
  1     0           0
```

Is this bad DB design? Is it possible without having to write two queries? (`INSERT INTO ballplayers; & INSERT INTO stats;`)Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have 2 choices: either you do it *manually* (2 insert queries into ballplayers then into stats) or you can use a trigger

Comment: One option may be to incorporate the stats and the player information into one table with the fields: id, playername, number, totalpts, totalrebounds.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/

Answer (score 0):

If you chose to go the route of a trigger, which would automatically add a row to the second table, you could do so using the following code:

```
create trigger trig_ballplayers_after_insert after insert on ballplayers
for each row insert ignore into stats values(new.id, 0, 0);
```